# Adding element name into a separate column when unnesting

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

When I unnest a column of lists, I want to make the element category or element names (`category1`, `category2` in the example below) to appear in a separate column as shown below. I tried using the .sep and .names_sep, but it doesn’t seem to work.

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:2,  apples = list(category1 = 1, category2 = 3:4))
```

[image]

```
df_un.a<-unnest(df, apples)
```

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Please use ``dput()`` function to show your data rather than post images. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
df %>% unnest(apples) %>% mutate(`Whatever name d.n matter` = paste0('category',x))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x apples `Whatever name d.n matter`
  <int>  <dbl> <chr>                     
1     1      1 category1                 
2     2      3 category2                 
3     2      4 category2
```